# Reduce function execution time in spike neural network

Tags: python, image, function, encoding, execution-time

I'm trying to generate spikes from image for spike neural networks. I do this with rate coding, where the probability of generating a spike corresponds to the pixel value. I test my function with 28x28 pixel image and the execution time was ~ 0.65 sec. If I'll generate spike using MNIST datset, it is gonna take about 10 hours to do, what is quite bad. How can I boost my function?

Here's the code I wrote:

```
def spike_generator(image_list, total_time, delay_time, frequency, seed=42):

    '''
    Function generates spike patterns based on the input data array.
    Probability of spiking corresponds to the pixel value.

    Parameters:

    image_list: list of numpy arrays containing input data for each neuron
    total_time (float): total duration for spike generation in seconds
    delay_time (float): time delay between spikes for each neuron in seconds
    frequency (int): frequency of spike generation in Hz
    seed (Optional(int), default = 42): a numerical value that
    generates a new set or repeats pseudo-random numbers

    Returns:

    generated_spikes: numpy array containing spike patterns
    for each neuron over the specified total_time duration
    '''

    np.random.seed(seed)
    generated_spikes = np.zeros((image_list.shape[0], image_list.shape[1], total_time * frequency))

    for z in range(image_list.shape[0]):
        data_norm = (image_list[z] - image_list[z].min()) / (image_list[z].max() - image_list[z].min())
        for i in range(image_list.shape[1]):
            while f <= total_time * frequency:
                if np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[1 - data_norm[i], data_norm[i]]) == 1:
                    generated_spikes[z][i][f] = 1
                    f = f + mt.ceil(frequency * delay_time)

    return generated_spikes
```

I've tried to use numpy.vectorize, but this didn't reduce execution time.

Comment: Have you tried a faster Python interpreter, like [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/)? Also, what's the point of the random choice if you're going to keep trying until it equals 1?

Comment: "I've tried to use numpy.vectorize, but this didn't reduce execution time" well it won't - it's [documented as such](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) - "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: `np.random.choice` is _slow_ in a loop. If you can pre-calculate an array of values in a single go, it works much faster. Other than than, look into `numba`, `pythran` and `cython`. There's nothing here for us to test with